# Hacer que en un alert salgan todos los valores seguidos

Tags: javascript, html

Mi codigo recorre un tabla de html y debe de mostrar en un alert los valores de las celdas separados con comas ej: valor1, valor2, valor3, ...

Mi problema es que al hacer un alert me muestra tal que así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado de mi alert

**Codigo html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ejercicio 4</title>
    <script src="../js/ejer4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Celda 11
            </td>
            <td>
                Celda 12
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Celda 21
            </td>
            <td>
                Celda 22
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
    <input type="button" id="btnRecorrer" value="Recorre Celdas">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="btnAnadir" value="Anadir Fila">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="btnBorrar" value="Borrar Fila">

</body>
</html>
```

**Codigo javascript**

```
window.onload = iniciarEventos

function iniciarEventos(){
    var btnRecorrer = document.getElementById("btnRecorrer")
    

    btnRecorrer.addEventListener("click", recorrer, false)

}


function recorrer(){
    var cadena = "";

    for(let step = 0; step < document.getElementsByTagName("td").length; step++){
        cadena += document.getElementsByTagName("td")[step].textContent + ","
    }

    alert(cadena)

}
```

Como he dicho antes mi idea es que no se muestren esos saltos de linea en el alert y salga todo en una linea. Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias

Comment: Te salen esos "saltos" porque si te fijas en tu archivo HTML, existe ese espacio entre la etiqueta y el contenido de la etiqueta. Puedes usar [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) para deshacerte de esos espacios al inicio y al final. Sería algo como: `...textContent.trim()`

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias‍

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque ha sido solucionada en comentarios

Comment: Si la respuesta está en los comentarios, pedile a @ricardo-dlc que lo escriba _como respuesta_, o escribila vos mismo/a, y [aceptala](/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: He puesto la respuesta yo mismo pero no me deja aceptarla hasta mañana. Mañana la acepto‍

Comment: ¿Por qué borraste tu respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion es la siguiente

Te salen esos "saltos" porque si te fijas en tu archivo HTML, existe ese espacio entre la etiqueta y el contenido de la etiqueta. Puedes usar .trim() para deshacerte de esos espacios al inicio y al final. Sería algo como: ...textContent.trim() . Autor: @ricardo-dlc Aqui dejo como sería la solucion:

Codigo javascript

```
window.onload = iniciarEventos

function iniciarEventos(){
    var btnRecorrer = document.getElementById("btnRecorrer")
    

    btnRecorrer.addEventListener("click", recorrer, false)

}


function recorrer(){
    var cadena = "";

    for(let step = 0; step < document.getElementsByTagName("td").length; step++){
        if(step == document.getElementsByTagName("td").length -1){
         cadena += document.getElementsByTagName("td")[step].textContent.trim()
        }
        cadena += document.getElementsByTagName("td")[step].textContent.trim() + ","
    }

    alert(cadena)

}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es la misma que la que hizo OP (autor de la pregunta), que de hecho ya la borró. ¿Qué pasó acá?

Comment: Algo extraño jajaja

Answer (score 0):

es porque en efecto tienes saltos de línea entre las celdas en el DOM luego de que tienes la etiqueta td indica salto de línea prueba esto`<td>Celda1</td>` y así sucesivamente

Comment: Aunque la resuesta esta en los comentarios de la pregunta muchas gracias